# Understanding awk delimiter - escaping in a regex-based field separator

Tags: awk, escaping, delimiter

I have the following shell command:

```
awk -F'\[|\]' '{print $2}'
```

What is this command doing? Split into fields using as delimiter `[sometext]`?

E.g.:

```
$ echo "this [line] passed to awk" | awk -F'\[|\]' '{print $2}'
line
```

<sup>Editor's note: Only [Mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/), as used on Ubuntu by default, produces the output above.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

The ***apparent*** intent is to treat *literal* `[` and `]` as field-separator characters, i.e., to split each input record into fields by each occurrence of `[` and/or `]`, which, with the sample line, yields `this`  as field 1 (`$1`), `line` as field 2 (`$2`), and  `passed to awk` as the last field (`$3`).

This is **achieved by a *regex* (regular expression)** that uses *alternation* (`|`), either side of which defines a field separator (delimiter): `\[` and `\]` in a regex are needed to represent *literal* `[` and `]`, because, by default, `[` and `]` are so-called *metacharacters* (characters with special syntactical meaning).
Note that `awk` *always* interprets the value of the `FS` variable (`-F` option) as a *regex*.

**However, the correct form is `'\\[|\\]'`**:

```
$ echo "this [line] passed to awk" | awk -F'\\[|\\]' '{print $2}'
line
```

That said, a more concise version that uses a character set (`[...]`) rather than alternation (`|`) is:

```
$ echo "this [line] passed to awk" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'
line
```

<sup>Note the careful placement of `]` before `[` inside the enclosing `[...]` to make this work, and how the *enclosing* `[...]` now have special meaning: they enclose a *set* of characters, any of which matches.</sup>

---

As for **why *2* `\` instances are needed in `'\\[|\\]'`**:

Taken as a regex *in isolation*, `\[|\]` would work:

- `\[` matches literal `[`
- `\]` matches literal `]`
- `|` is an alternation that matches one or the other.

However, **Awk's *string* processing comes first**:

- It *should*, due to `\` handling in a *string*, reduce `\[|\]` to `[|]` *before* interpretation as a *regex*.

  - Unfortunately, however, [Mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/), the default Awk on Ubuntu, for instance, resorts to *guesswork* in this particular scenario.<sup>[1]</sup>
- `[|]`, interpreted as a regex, would then only match a *single, literal* `|`

Thus, **the robust and portable way is to use `\\` in a *string literal* when you mean to pass a *single* `\` as part of a *regex*.**

This quote from the [relevant section of the GNU Awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) sums it up well:

> To get a backslash into a regular expression inside a string, you have to type two backslashes.

---

[1] **Implementation differences:**

Unfortunately, at least 1 major Awk implementation resorts to *guesswork* in the presence of a single `\` before a regex metacharacter inside a string literal.

BSD/macOS Awk and GNU Awk act predictably and GNU Awk also issues a helpful warning when a singly `\`-prefixed regex metacharacter is found:

```
# GNU Awk: Predictable string-first processing + a helpful warning.
echo 'a[b]|c' | gawk -F'\[|\]' '{print $2}'
gawk: warning: escape sequence '\[' treated as plain '['
gawk: warning: escape sequence '\]' treated as plain ']'
c

# BSD/macOS Awk: Predictable string-first processing, no warning.
echo 'a[b]|c' | awk -F'\[|\]' '{print $2}'
c

# Mawk: *Guesses* that a *regex* was intended.
#       The unambiguous form -F'\\[|\\]' works too, fortunately.
echo 'a[b]|c' | mawk -F'\[|\]' '{print $2}'
b
```

---

#### Optional reading: *regex* literals *inside* Awk scripts

Awk supports *regex* literals enclosed in `/.../`, the use of which bypasses the double-escaping problem.

However:

- These literals (which are invariably constant) are only available *inside* an Awk script,
- *and*, it seems, you can only use them as *patterns* or *function arguments* - you cannot store them in a *variable*.

Therefore, even though `/\[|\]/` is *in principle* equivalent to `"\\[|\\]"`, you can *not* use the following, because the regex literal cannot be assigned to (special) variable `FS`:

```
# !! DOES NOT WORK in any of the 3 major Awk implementations.
#    Note that nothing is output, and no error/warning is displayed.
$ echo 'a[b]|c' | awk 'BEGIN { FS=/\[|\]/ } { print $2 }'

# Using a double-escaped *string* to house the regex again works as expected:
$ echo 'a[b]|c' | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\\[|\\]" } { print $2 }'
b
```