# Awk multi character field separator containing caret not working as expected

Tags: awk

I have tried multiple google searches, but none of the proposed answers are working for my example below. NF should be 3, but I keep getting 1.

```
# cat a
1^%2^%3
# awk -F^% '{print NF}' a
1
# awk -F'^%' {print NF}' a
1
awk -F "^%" {print NF}' a
1
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-F` variable in `awk` takes a regular expression as its value. So the value `^` is interpreted as a special anchor regex pattern which need to be deprived of its special meaning. So you escape it a with a literal backslash `\` character

```
awk -F'\\^%' '{ print NF }'
```

from [GNU Awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html) for Escape Sequences

> The backslash character itself is another character that cannot be included normally; you must write `\\` to put one backslash in the string or regexp. Thus, the string whose contents are the two characters `"` and `\` must be written `\"\\`.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape `^` to remove its special meaning which is getting used as a regex by field separator.Once you escape `^` by doing `\\^` it will be treated as a normal/literal character and then `^%` will be considered as string and you will get answer as 3.

```
awk -F'\\^%' '{print NF}' Input_file
```

Here is one nice SO link which you could take it as an example too for better understanding, it doesn't talk about specifically `^` character but it talks about how to use escape sequence in field separator in `awk`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44072825/5866580

Comment: This works, but only with double back-slash, what is the purpose of double back-slash? I tried it with a single back-slash before the carrot and did not work.

Comment: @usao, \\ means we are letting `awk`'s field separator know that the character after it is a literal character and should NOT be treated as a regex pattern. Usually `^` is used in regex pattern matching, eg--> `^var` means if something starts with `^` but here it is not he case as your file has it as a letter, so hence we need to escape it.